# Can Google Sheets be opened/edited in Ubuntu?

Tags: google-drive

I have a number of Google Sheets (spreadsheets) saved on Google Drive normally accessed from an android phone collaboratively but would like to edit them from within Ubuntu.

I can save the file as either an .ods (LibreCalc) or .xlsx (MS Excel) file from android and whilst either formats can be edited in LibreCalc I cannot find a way of successfully re-saving the file in the Sheets format back to Google Drive for continued collaboration.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use Google Drive files offline

This answer requires Google Chrome web browser to be installed and regularly updated.

> If you aren't connected to a Wi-Fi or mobile network, you can still
> view and edit files, including:
>
> - Google Docs
> - Google Sheets
> - Google Slides
>
> #### Open files offline
>
> To turn on offline access:
>
> - You must be connected to the Internet.
> - Use  the Google Chrome browser.
> - Don't use incognito mode.
> - Install and enable [Google Docs offline Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-docs-offline/ghbmnnjooekpmoecnnnilnnbdlolhkhi). The Google Docs extension makes it possible to edit your documents, spreadsheets and presentations when you aren’t connected to the internet. Plus, you can copy and paste between Docs, Sheets and Slides.
> - Make sure you have enough free space on your device to save your files.
>
> #### Open your Google Drive files offline
>
> - Open Chrome. Make sure you're [signed in to Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/185277).
> - Go to [drive.google.com/drive/settings](https://drive.google.com/drive/settings).
> - Check the box in the **Offline** category next to "Sync Google Docs, Sheets, Slides & Drawings files to this computer so that you can edit offline."

<sub>**Source:** [Use Google Drive files offline – Google Drive Help](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375012?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)</sub>

Comment: and it works just as well on-line automatically saving changes to the android app. Brilliant!